# Cordova install on Linux

Tags: cordova, ubuntu, command-line-interface, sencha-touch-2

How can I install Cordova on Ubuntu/xUbuntu?

My attempts at executing [npm install cordova](https://npmjs.org/package/cordova) as directed from the link and other sources didn't work.

I get the following long error message:

```
root@li141-82:/var/www/mysite# npm install cordova
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: cordova
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:156:14)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (http.js:1256:7)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /var/www/mysite/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.6-x86_64-linode35
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/mysite
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.19
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: cordova
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/mysite/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com), a tool which is based on Cordova. To install PhoneGap you need to install node, then `sudo npm install -g phonegap`.

If you just need Cordova then you can download the zip file [here](http://cordova.apache.org/#download).

Comment: Thank you. Worked after I installing node.js according to this post - http://askubuntu.com/questions/49390/how-do-i-install-the-latest-version-of-node-js

Comment: This answer is out of date, see @steinar's answer below

Answer (score 54):

You need to set the NPM registry

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: When i set this registry four lines is worked and then stucked without showing anything.                                                                                    npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http 304 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-2.8.1.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/cordova/-/cordova-2.8.1.tgz.            After this nothing is showing. I tried 3 times and same thing hapened.

Answer (score 1):

follow following commands for installing cordova on ubuntu :

1. $ sudo apt-get install npm

2. $ sudo npm install node

3. $ sudo npm install -g cordova

4. $ cordova

if it showing no command found then use alternate :

 1.$ sudo apt-get remove node

 2. $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make

3. $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js

4. $ sudo apt-get update

5. $ sudo apt-get install nodejs

6. $ sudo npm install -g cordova

7. $ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node

Answer (score 0):

look at [the documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface) :

```
sudo npm install -g cordova
```