# How can I install cordova in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ubuntu

I try to run `sudo npm install -g cordova` in Ubuntu 12.04. I get this error:

> info it worked if it ends with ok
>   verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/bin/npm', 'install', '-g', 'cordova' ]
>   info using npm@1.1.4
>   info using node@v0.6.12
>   verbose config file /home/desarrollador/.npmrc
>   verbose config file /usr/etc/npmrc
>   verbose config file /usr/share/npm/npmrc
>   silly exec /usr/bin/node "/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js" "nobody" 1001
>   silly spawning [ '/usr/bin/node',
>   silly spawning   [ '/usr/share/npm/bin/npm-get-uid-gid.js', 'nobody', 1001 ],
>   silly spawning   null ]
>   silly output from getuid/gid {"uid":65534,"gid":1001}
>   silly output from getuid/gid
>   verbose cache add [ 'cordova', null ]
>   silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'cordova', [ 'cordova', null ] ]
>   verbose parsed url { pathname: 'cordova', path: 'cordova', href: 'cordova' }
>   verbose addNamed [ 'cordova', '' ]
>   verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
>   silly name, range, hasData [ 'cordova', '', false ]
>   verbose raw, before any munging cordova
>   verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './cordova' ]
>   verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: cordova
>   ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
>   ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
>   ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
>   ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
>   ERR!     at Request. (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
>   ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
>   ERR!     at ClientRequest. (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
>   ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
>   ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
>   ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
>   ERR! You may report this log at:
>   ERR!     http://bugs.debian.org/npm
>   ERR! or use
>   ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/desarrollador/npm-debug.log npm
>   ERR!
>   ERR! System Linux 3.5.0-59-generic
>   ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "cordova"
>   ERR! cwd /home/desarrollador
>   ERR! node -v v0.6.12
>   ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
>   ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: cordova

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cordova install on Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207948/cordova-install-on-linux)

Answer (score 1):

follow following commands for installing cordova on ubuntu : 

1. $ sudo apt-get install npm 

2. $ sudo npm install node 

3. $ sudo npm install -g cordova 

4. $ cordova

if it showing no command found then use alternate : 

1.$ sudo apt-get remove node 

2. $ sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make 

3. $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js 

4. $ sudo apt-get update 

5. $ sudo apt-get install nodejs 

6. $ sudo npm install -g cordova 

7. $ ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node